# how to get working Ajax.BeginForm ,when i click a decision button

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, razor

In view part:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoFUPTrialDecision", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "FUPTrialInputs" }))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("ClientLoanID", Model.ClientLoanID)
        <table >
            <tr>
            <th class="td2Fld" >
                Unemployment Benefits Effective: &nbsp;
            </th>
            <td class="SrcFld">
                <div>
                 @Html.TextBox("BeginDate", Model.BeginDate)&nbsp;   
                @Html.RequiredFieldFor(model => model.BeginDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BeginDate)
                To &nbsp; @Html.TextBox("EndDate", Model.EndDate)
                @Html.RequiredFieldFor(model => model.EndDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate)
                </div>
          }
```

In Model:

```
public class UnEmploymentInputs : UserInputs
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime? BeginDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [GreaterThan("BeginDate")] 
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? NonEscrowTax { get; set; }
    public decimal? NonEscrowInsurance { get; set; }
    public bool? IsExtension { get; set; }
    public bool? IsIncomeCircumstance { get; set; }
}

public class HUPTrialInputs : UnEmploymentInputs
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Previous Plan duration is invalid")]
    [DisplayName("Previous Plan Duration")] 
    public short PreviousPlanDuration { get; set; }
}

public class FUPTrialInputs : UnEmploymentInputs
{

    public short ExtensionDuration { get; set; }
    public bool IsPreviouslyApproved { get; set; }
    public bool IsPreviouslyDelinquencyCured { get; set; }
    public decimal RentalIncome { get; set; }
    public decimal MonthlySecuredDebts { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please specify what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please make sure that you didn't forget to include these libs:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It's very easy to forget and there is not visible errors but things don't work.